# How to setup middleware for API request in Vue 3 composition API with typescript

Tags: typescript, api, vuejs3

I would like to make like middleware when i make API call.

This where i make the call

```
  getAll: () => {
   return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    .get('/posts/')
    .then((data) => console.log(data.data))})}
```

If it was without TS I would make schema file and i will map there

```
 .then((data) => res.data.data.map(schema.Posts))})}
```

*schema*

```
export const schemas = {
  return { 
    Posts: { 
      body: data.body,
      id: data.id,
      title: data.title,
      userId:1
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the best practices with TS and how to make it.